# Allow users to restore prior days DB to view

Tags: sql-server, restore, role

Our application backs up DB at end of day to save End Of Day picture.

We need to allow users ( Windows domain users) to restore these prior days backups using our app.
This needs to done through a proc that a users can call.
Need help getting this to work.  What does the user need to execute this proc as? Does the user need permissions assigned at run time?   Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not automatically restore the backup that was just taken to <database>_EOD or something named like that?  Then you get to test your backups every day as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  They need flexibility to restore a backup for any business day.

Comment: Think very carefully about your path and where it leads. This functionality will eventually overwhelm your database engine and storage. Once users discover how easily they can create a copy for any date, they will do exactly that. Over and Over and Over.

Comment: Anything built if used incorrectly can have issues.  We have built some safeguards. Like Only allowing a single user at a time to use functionality.  It is something that the users need.  Still hoping for some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

RESTORE

If the database being restored does not exist, the user must have CREATE DATABASE permissions to be able to execute RESTORE. If the database exists, RESTORE permissions belong by default to members of the sysadmin and dbcreator fixed server roles and the owner (dbo) of the database (for the FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT option, the database always exists).

RESTORE permissions are given to roles in which membership information is always readily available to the server. Because fixed database role membership can be checked only when the database is accessible and undamaged, which is not always the case when RESTORE is executed, members of the db_owner fixed database role do not have RESTORE permissions.